# Obtener años y dias a partir de N dias en Swfit

Tags: swift

Obtengo la diferencia de dias entre dos fechas en Swift, me gustaria que se pueda representar cuantos años representan más los dias extras.

```swift
let days = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).numberOfDaysBetween(from: dateOne!, to: dateTwo!)
print("days beetween dates: \(days) days")`
//2261 days
```

es decir que los 2261 dias, sean N años y N dias

Answer (score 1):

La matemática para esta calculacion puede ser echa con la function `calendar.dateComponents(components: Set<Calendar.Component>, from: Date, to: Date)`

```
let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let dateOne = Date()
let dateTwo =  calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 2261, to: Date())!
//Calcula la differencia usando los componentes que quieras
let diferencia = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .day], from: dateOne, to: dateTwo)
let ano = diferencia.year
let dias = diferencia.day

print("days beetween dates: \(ano ?? 0) years, \(dias ?? 0) days")
//days beetween dates: 6 years, 69 days
```

Answer (score 0):

El final lo he realizado de la sieguiente forma

```swift
    let days = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).numberOfDaysBetween(from: dateOne!, to: dateTwo!)
    //print("days beetween dates: \(days) days")

    let years = days / 365
    let restOfDays = days - (years * 365)

    print("\(years) years and \(restOfDays) days")
```

Muestra: 6 years 71 days

Código testeable en
https://swiftfiddle.com/c6sjbarkszfjjesqfiltbxgmbm